# How do I use a directory name as variable for apache.conf?

Tags: php, apache, webserver, httpd.conf

I dont have much coding experience and Im still learning.

This is a separate config file that is Included on the httpd.conf

I have a large apache config and would like to use variables to clean up the config file. My config file has over 80 similar entries that I believe can be cleaned up if I could figure out how to use the variables.
I want to take the name of the files with in a directory and use it as the variable.
Directory here is /www/pub/sites/8.0/conf/ inside the conf file are the php files of the sites. I want to make or use the name of any file that has .php at the end and use the name as the variable. So if there's a file called clark apache would use the variable ${siteName}
which would be a file called clark.php. Hope I'm explaining myself correctly or you can at least understand what I want to do.

```
    Redirect /direct /direct.php
<Directory /pub/www/sites/8.0/htdocs>
    Require all granted
    # Enable ".htaccess" to password protect directories.
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

Alias /forms /pub/www/sites/forms

<Directory /pub/www/sites/forms>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv siteName gentry
    DocumentRoot "/pub/www/sites/8.0/htdocs"
    ServerName gentry.testwebs.com
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv siteName foster
    DocumentRoot "/pub/www/sites/8.0/htdocs"
    ServerName foster.testwebs.com
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv siteName mcintosh
    DocumentRoot "/pub/www/sites/8.0/htdocs"
    ServerName mcintosh.testwebs.com
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv siteName clark
    DocumentRoot "/pub/www/sites/8.0/htdocs"
    ServerName clark.testwebs.com
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

#code basically repeats itself. etc ........
code here
```

The config below gives me an error when I start apache.

[Wed Jul 07 08:09:41.846350 2021] [core:warn] [pid 21457:tid 140546613625472] AH00111: Config variable ${siteName} is not defined

Could I clean it up using something like this?

```
SetEnv sitesName "/www/pub/sites/8.0/conf/${sitesName}.php"

<Directory /pub/www/sites/8.0/htdocs>
    Require all granted
    # Enable ".htaccess" to password protect directories.
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

Alias /forms /pub/www/sites/forms
<Directory /pub/www/sites/forms>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv sitesName "/www/pub/sites/8.0/conf/${sitesName}.php"
    DocumentRoot "/pub/www/sites/8.0/htdocs"
    ServerName ${sitesName}.testwebs.com
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

[/code]
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you searching for is a apache2 module called `mod_vhost_alias`
You can enable that using

```sh
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then you should edit your configuration with something like that

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/%-2"
</VirtualHost>
```

More info, like variable details and sources on that [article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-dynamic-virtual-hosts-with-apache-and-the-mod-vhost-alias-module)

Comment: How would I only filter it to use the files with the .php extension. Wouldnt this include all files in that directory?
How would I retain the domain. and keep everything with a .php as a subdomain. to the testwebs.com?

Comment: You can add the rest of your configuration inside that exemple, you can use the variables in any directives.